# I want to add a required field to textinputlayout with red asterisk in xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to add a required field to textinputlayout with red asterisk in xamarin Android.Having Any idea about this. I tried to find in google but not get any solution.

http://prntscr.com/mfjv7k

Comment: If you read the [material design documentation](https://material.io/design/color/#color-color-schemes) and check the images of required fields no where does it show a red asterik and i suggest you follow the material design docs. Where it shows required documents with an asterik mark but no red color on the asterik but the same color as the rest of the text

Answer (score 0):

To add *asterics* to your `TextView` you need to use `SpannableStringBuilder`. Refer to the code shown here:

```
var txt = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.textInputEditText1);
TextView text = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.textView1);
string simple = "CREATE PASSWORD";
string colored = "*";
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
builder.Append(simple);
int start = builder.Length();
builder.Append(colored);
int end = builder.Length();
builder.SetSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.Red), start, end,SpanTypes.ExclusiveExclusive);
text.SetText(builder, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
```

axml code

```
<TextView
    android:text="Create Password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView1" />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="123456767888"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textInputEditText1"
    android:password="true" />
```

Output screenshot

[image]

Comment: This is not the write answer he wants it in text input layout not a textview

Comment: @G.hakim - Please check screenshot provided by OP. How that is possible in _text input layout_.

Comment: Why isn't it possible using textinputlayout i am pretty sure that is exactly how and edittext looks like in a textinputlayout when focused

Comment: @G.hakim - I tried it doesn't seem that easy. If I am using _*_ in axml projecting not executing. If I am adding it problematically `Hint` not moving towards top and color isn't showing red if add `Hint` problematically.

Comment: See my comment on the question